# What are the enumerations?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy, the-thousand-sons

In many of the Horus Heresy books the Thousand Sons legions use the enumerations. These are numbered, I THINK there are eight (although I don't know where I got that from) and we know each are numbered.

What exactly are the enumerations and what are the properties of each?

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact definition. 
The "enumerations" are something like a state of mind and way to focus in the warp. You may chant for a while and reach one of the lower enumerations, which again help you reach the higher ones. So naturally, you progress. There are no properties to them as far as i can tell, except that they give you the ability to be more in sync with the warp, from my point of view.

There are no other references to this.

Comment: Can you [edit] in quotes/evidence to back this up?

Answer (score 1):

In The Crimson King, a soul divided they shed **some** more light on the enumerations, it would seem that the psycic powers and the enumerations are definitely linked. for example:

> When Ahriman landed back on Prospero to for the reanaction of the burning he noted that a fellow legionary named Sanakht(a master swordsman) preferred to stay in the 4th enumeration even in combat because it allowed to him link him more with other beings and thus it was easier for him to perceive the near future allowing him to predict his opponents move.
>  Further on in this event Ahriman again warned his fellow brothers to **"Only stay in the first enumeration"** The reason for this is that there was so much suppressed psycic energy that the change would quickly overtake them should they use their powers too much. Him saying that certainly implies that the higher you go in the enumerations the greater power one will be able to wield.
>  Again a bit further Ahriman was talking about the elite scarab guard and noted that these warriors all had achieved the rank of "Philophisous" and mastered all the enumerations like himself. 
>  It also seems like the different orders within the legions prefer different enumerations because they seem to work better with certain powers.

I do not know of any other sources except of Ahriman that go in depth and explain anything about the enumerations, so we kinda have to trust him on it(he is the chief librarian of the 1000 Sons so he would also be the most qualified on the subject)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the enumerations are levels of meditation. The deeper one goes the more they suppress their ego, allowing them to access the warp more easily as the warp makes no sense to someone with a functioning ego. Only by forgetting what you know to be true in the physical world through meditation can you comprehend the nature of the warp. That's my take on it anyway. I came to this conclusion by taking into consideration the descriptions of the enumerations in the book A Thousand Sons and how the warp is described to be maddening to a sane mind, not following the rules of reality as we know them.

Comment: Could you [edit] in some of the quotes from the book if they are short enough to back this up?